# How to stretch labels dynamically in Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, label

I'm a new developer and I'm working on a small project, which contain these components: `textField`,  `label`, `button`.

Every time the user hits the button the data on the text box should go to the label like this:

```
label = "\(label) \n " + "\(textfield)"
```

so if I have this two entries: `21, 12` it should look like this in the label:

```
21
12
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your label is of type `UILabel` and you have placed it on your storyboard in Xcode. Therefore you should not reassign the `var`, but change its `text` property. This would look like

```
label.text = "\(label.text), \(textfield.text)"
```

This will add the text to the single line the label usually covers. I do not think newlines do work well in there.

Comment: what if I want to create a new label each time the user press the button ?  is there a good way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a good way , which is : replacing label with text view that gave me the ability to go to the next line :) Thanks guys I hope this can answer someone's question in future